# Parameterize UrlMappings in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I had this idea that I wanted to assign prefixes to my two categories of URLs. One category would be

```
/baseurl/api/$controller
```

for secured REST URLs and then:

```
/baseurl/register/$action
```

for the current one category of unsecured URLs

I then thought it would be good to store the prefixes /api and /register in variables so they could be referenced elsewhere if need be (such as my security configuration). However, I can't get this to work in my UrlMappings. None of the variables defining the URL parts seem to be populated. Consider the following UrlMappings.groovy where I've defined a SignupController.groovy to map to registration, and every other controller is API related:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static final API_URL_ROOT = "/api"
    static final REGISTER_URL_ROOT = "/register"
    static mappings = {
        API_URL_ROOT + "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
            constraints {

            }
        }

        REGISTER_URL_ROOT (controller: "signup")

        "/"(view: "/index")
        "500"(view: '/error')
        "404"(view: '/notFound')
    }
}
```

When this runs I can only invoke my controllers through the root URL directly, ie, `localhost:8080/login` and `localhost:8080/signup` whereas I want it to be:

`localhost:8080/api/v1/login` and `localhost:8080/register/signup`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Was my answer to your question still not satisfactory? If not, could you accept it

Answer (score 0):

You could use group to separate your different api

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-grouping-url-mappings.html?m=1

In your case it could become something like that

```
group("/api") { 
     "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" { constraints { } }
     // PUT HERE ALL OTHER API MAPPING
} 

group("/register") { 
    "/$controller" {} 
    // PUT HERE ALL REGISTER MAPPINGS 
}
```

If you need to take into consideration a version for your api just do this

```
group("/api") {
    "/$namespace/$controller/$action/$id?" {}
    // OR ANY OTHER MAPPING YOU NEED. Then in your controller define
    // static namespace = 'v1' 
    // for example for your v1 controllers.
}
```

Then you can declare you groups as variables if you want.

```
 static API="/api"

 group (API) { .... }
```

Hope that helps if not sorry for the noise

Comment: How would that help? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem I'm describing unless I'm missing something...